# Copyright of chessmonk and other pieces

Tags: pieces

I want to use some of the chess pieces in my app from [pychess](https://github.com/pychess/pychess/tree/master/pieces) But for some pieces, there is no clue about their license or author

for example, I want to use [chessmonk](https://github.com/pychess/pychess/tree/master/pieces/chessmonk) chess pieces in my commercial app, But I can't find the license for these pieces, I searched a lot

Please give me some advice

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot give you legal advice.

Comment: Send a message to the author.

Comment: @SmallChess Thanks for the comment, But I can't find the author of those pieces either.